# Azure service bus client in timer triggered azure function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I have a service bus where some of messages must be handled in the correct order, which is not always the order they were added to the service bus.

I am receiving the messages in an Azure function and I basically need batch functionality, which I know is not available.

**Question** I would like to know if I can make a timer triggered function that empties the service bus each time it is called?

Comment: Yes, you can. However, how are you going to proceed with all the messages if one of them fails? And is there value in the (separate) messages if you need other messages to get to the right processing order? You might want to have a good look at the current implementation.

Comment: The idea would be to use a durable orchestration function that batch processes whatever is retrieved from the service bus each time the function triggers. It would take care of both the ordering and fault handling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can purge the messages inside a Service Bus Queue whenever the Function is triggered.

You can receive messages in Receive and Delete mode to do that. Check here for [samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-get-started-with-queues#receive-messages-from-the-queue).